# Can I work around this iOS 8 Voiceover bug in UIWebView?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, voiceover

There's [a bug in iOS 8.0 with Voiceover in UIWebView](http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5842403076341760). I've filed it on Apple's bug report site and also made a copy available on OpenRadar where you can read it.

> Summary: Consider a UIViewController containing a UIWebView whose HTML
>   content is long enough that it scrolls off the screen; at the bottom
>   of the HTML is a button. Voiceover users can right-swipe through the
>   content to have the text read aloud.
>
> But when the Voiceover user swipes to the button and double-taps to
>   activate the button, nothing happens; its onclick event handler never
>   fires.

**Is there a way to work around this bug?** Or do our Voiceover users just have to wait around for Apple to fix this bug in a patch release to iOS 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workaround is to switch to WKWebView. The bug exists in UIWebView, but not WKWebView.